# Framebuffer's RGB colors are different when alpha value is modified

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have fragment shader that writes to framebuffer's texture. I have 2 shaders that use the framebuffer's output texture. First uses just alpha and Second just RGB. When framebuffer's shader return `fragmentColor.a = 0` the RGB component completely dissapear when used in Second shader even when I set `fragmentColor.a` to `1` manually. Is it possible to prevent this "RGB dissapear" or am I getting some bug? Yes I can generate different textures for each shader but it costs huge amount of perfomance because even with only one "draw" it's very costly. But if I could output to two textures at same time that would also solve whole problem. Anyone has any advice/solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have blending enabled and set `glBlendFunc` to something like `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`, which will also affect the destination alpha values. To overcome this there's separable blending, set it up with `glBlendFuncSeparate[i]` and choose the source and destination equations so that the RGB values are passed through as needed for your application. Use the *"i"* variant to set different blending functions for each fragment shader output target (if you have a single fragment shader with multiple outputs), or call the non-"i" version multiple times, before each render pass to set it up for your individual fragment shaders.